# Convertir HTTPS a etiqueta <a href=""> con php

Tags: php

Tengo el siguiente código PHP:

```
$linea = "Fuente: https://www.unsitioweb.com";
$datos = explode(" ", substr($linea, 0,7));
$https = "https://";
$encontrado = false;

foreach ($datos as $protocolo) {
    if ($protocolo == $https) {
        $encontrado = true;
    }
}

if ($encontrado) {echo "<a href='$linea'>Link encontrado</a>";}
else {echo "Sin protocolo";}
```

En teoría la función que debería cumplir es que si en algún momento encuentra "**https**" se convierta a etiqueta  con su respectivo link. De esta manera:

```
<a href="https://www.unsitioweb.com">Link encontrado</a>
```

Pero no me está funcionando, si estoy haciendo algo mal o hay una forma más efectiva de hacerlo agradecería sus respuestas.

Comment: El llamado `$valor = substr($linea, 0,7);` te devuelve "fuente:" si a ese valor le estás aplicando `explode(' ', $valor);` obtienes un array con un elemento $datos = ["fuente:"]; y al recorrerlo no vas a encontrar nunca el protocolo https.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error principal esta en esta línea:

```
$datos = explode(" ", substr($linea, 0,7));
```

Que si prestas atención, primero acortas las cadena siete caracteres y luego la separas por espacios

#### Solución:

Lo que podrías hacer es:

1. Separar la cadena por el espacio y analizar solo la última parte (`eg $link = explode(" ", $linea)[1];`)
2. Obtener solo el protocolo a validar (`eg: $protocol = substr($link, 0, 8);`)
3. Y finalmente validar si son iguales (`eg: if ($protocol == $https)`)

#### Ejemplo:

```
<?php
$linea = "Fuente: https://www.unsitioweb.com";
$link = explode(" ", $linea)[1];
$protocolo = substr($link, 0, 8);
$https = "https://";

if ($protocolo == $https) {echo "<a href='$link'>Link encontrado</a>";}
else {echo "Sin protocolo";}
```

**PD:** Podrias ahorrarte hacer `$link = explode(" ", $linea)[1];` y directamente hacer `$link = substr($linea, 8);`

Answer (score 1):

Puedes intentar con el siguiente codigo, lo que cambie fue el foreach por un strpos.
La función strpos() encuentra la posición de la primera aparición de una cadena dentro de otra cadena.

```
$linea = "Fuente: https://www.unsitioweb.com";
$datos = explode(" ", substr($linea, 0,7));
$https = "https://";
$encontrado = false;

if (strpos($linea, 'https://') !== false) {
   $encontrado = true;
}

if ($encontrado) {echo "<a href='$linea'>Link encontrado</a>";}
else {echo "Sin protocolo";}
```

Comment: Para otros visitantes: Este método también funciona perfectamete :D
Gracias Franco